# D3.js: Get an array of the data attached to a selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to get an array of all the data attached to a selection in D3.

I'm working with the example from the [General Update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218), and trying this:

```
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(data, function(d) { return d; });

var textEnter = text.enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "enter")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });

console.log('textEnter data', textEnter[0]);

var textEnterKeys = d3.map(textEnter[0], function(d) { 
  return d.__data__;
});

console.log('textEnterKeys', textEnterKeys);
```

But `textEnterKeys` just looks exactly the same as `textEnter`. How can I get an array of the data attached to each element in the selection?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can simply call `.data()` without any arguments on a selection to get the bound data. See [the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data):

> If values is not specified, then this method returns the array of data for the first group in the selection. The length of the returned array will match the length of the first group, and the index of each datum in the returned array will match the corresponding index in the selection. If some of the elements in the selection are null, or if they have no associated data, then the corresponding element in the array will be undefined.

This does not work for the `.enter()` selection as there are no elements yet to which the data can be bound. In this case, the `.map` function can be used:

```
textEnter.map(function(d) { return d.__data__; });
```

Comment: Great - I can get the update data by doing `text.data()`. I can't however get the enter data by doing `text.enter().data()` as I would expect - could you tell me how to get the bound data for the enter selection?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't get the data as you would expect?

Comment: If I try to invoke `text.enter().data()` in the line after `var text = ....`, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'data'`. However, `text.data()` works just as you say.

Comment: ... and indeed if I do `console.dir(text.enter()`) I can see that there is no `.data` method available on it.

Comment: Right, that's because the elements in the `.enter()` selection don't actually exist yet. You can get them by subtracting the `.update()` selection from the entire data you pass in though.

Comment: Err... Yes they do, if I do `console.dir(text.enter())` I can see an array of 26 items, each with a bound `__data__` attribute.

Comment: Obviously the DOM elements don't exist yet, but that doesn't mean the data isn't in the enter selection. I want a simple way to see which data is in update, which is in enter, and which is in exit, following a data bind.

Comment: I mean the DOM elements that `.data()` uses. You can of course write your own function that gets whatever is stored in `__data__`. It should work if, in the code you've posted, you replace `d3.map(textEnter[0]...` with `d3.map(textEnter...`.

Comment: No, that gives me a `d3_Map` object, and `d3_Map[0]` seems to be an array of text objects, each of which does have a `.__data__` property... I just want the data!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28371/discussion-between-richard-and-lars-kotthoff)

Comment: I'm new to d3js, so it took me a while to figure out that my data was down in `'.bar'` like this: `var data = d3.select(chart.get(0)).selectAll('.bar').data();`

Comment: In case of nested selections, the `.data()` call only recovers the data for the first subgroup. Also, the way `.filter()` works, if you eliminate all elements from the first subgroup, even then `.data()` returns that subgroup, obviously empty.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the entire data array from within a modification function, e.g., `selection.attr`, you can use the fact that the entire selection is passed to the modification function as its third argument. So you can reconstruct the data array as follows:

```js
mySelection.attr("stroke", (_, __, nodes) => {
  let data = d3.selectAll(nodes).data()
  // Now you can use data.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I was also wondering about it.  The state passed in through selection.data is not lost but it is dispersed across the update and enter groups.  It can be retrieved, in tact, reasonably reliably with this function...

```
function getData2(/*this is update*/) {
    if (this.enter /*quick duck type test...*/) {
        var enter = this.enter(), retVal = []

        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {

            retVal.push([])

            for (var j = 0; j < enter.length; j++) {
                retVal[i].push(enter[i][j] || enter[i].update[j])
                retVal[i][j] = retVal[i][j] && retVal[i][j].__data__
                if (!retVal[i][j]) {
                    retVal[i].pop()
                } 
            }

        }
        return (this.length > 1 ? retVal : retVal[0])
    }
}
```

usage...

```
console.log(getData2.call(update))
```

OR...

```
d3.selection.prototype.data2 = getData2
// ...
console.log(update.data2())
```

where `update` is the update collection returned by selection.data(array)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `datum()` to get the data if you used `datum(someData)` to bind.