# How to convert a jQuery object into a d3 object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a Problem with using jQuery together with D3js.

I have a jQuery element named "elem" and I want to do some D3js functions.

This code works:

```
d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 300).attr("height", 300).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(150,150)").selectAll("text").data(words).enter().append("text")......
```

This code does not

```
elem.append("svg").attr("width", 300).attr("height", 300).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(150,150)").selectAll("text").data(words).enter().append("text")......
```

So how to convert the jQuery Object into a D3 Object?

Comment: I don't really understand why this question is being downvoted so heavily. It seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: You can't convert from jquery to D3. Select the element directly with D3 instead.

Comment: It is possible obviously...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can get the DOM Elements themselves from the jQuery object using [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) method or array notation on the jquery object, and then select them with d3 selector like you would any DOM Element.

Note that while both works, [jQuery faq mentions that array notation is faster.](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)

```
d3.select($("#selection").get(0));
d3.select($("#selection")[0]); // equivalent to above but faster
```

*Edit: Thanks to [Ken Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606263/ken-fox) for pointing out jQuery faq.*

Comment: I'm new to d3js, so it took me a while to figure out that my data was down in `'.bar'` like this: `var data = d3.select(chart.get(0)).selectAll('.bar').data();` http://stackoverflow.com/a/16057614/470749

Comment: Just a quick note:<br/>
As per the [docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/), it would be faster to do `d3.select($("#selection")[0]);`

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert the objects directly. You need to re-select the element using `d3js`. `d3js` selectors work like this

```
d3.select("#mydiv")
```

So simply extract the `id` from the `jQuery` element like so

```
d3.select("#" + elem.attr("id")).append("svg").attr("width", 300)...
```

Of course if you're only using `jQuery` to select the element, then you should switch to `d3js` selection instead.

EDIT: I prefer Ozan's answer above, use that!